# Input array for php mail to function

Tags: php

Can the php mail function accept an array of emails as the to input?  For example I'm trying to email a list of users the same message.

Single email:

```
mail("dylan@gmail.com","","subject","from:<someond@domain.com>);
```

Is this possible?
Multiple recipients email:

```
mail("[array of email addresses]","","subject","from:<someond@domain.com>);
```

I have a sql dB with the list of emails I was going to create a json endpoint to create the array of emails and then want to input that array into the php mail function to email all users the same message.

Comment: The [official PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) shows what the acceptable inputs are.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 1):

Use implode to concatenate email adresses in one string:

```
$emails = [...];
mail(implode(",", $emails),"subject","message");
```